# Customising search results in twentyseventeen using content-search.php

Tags: php, wordpress

**Using a child theme based on the twentyseventeen theme**, I customised

`theme/template-parts/content.php`

My modification changes the way the main posts page presents the list of blogposts.

However, I'd like this change to be reflected in search results, too, but I'm not sure how to.

The file `search.php` tells me to customise results content by creating a `content-search.php` file, which I *think* should reside in `theme/template-parts/content-search.php`.

I tried copying the contents of `theme/template-parts/content.php` and placing that in a file at `theme/template-parts/content-search.php`, but tinkering with minor adjustments to that file seem to show no difference to my search results.

So how do I customize search results content in my twentyseventeen child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Your own file should be in the 
/template-parts/**posts**/ folder of your theme. That's where `get_template_part` is looking for it:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' );
```

As for what to call the file:

The comments in the theme's search.php say to use "content-search.php" but that file isn't used in twentyseventeen. I think this comment must be left over from previous incarnations of the themes (e.g. twentyfifteen does use content-search.php to display the search results) and is possibly wrong.

The file that is currently used to display the results is 
`twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content-excerpt.php`

We can tell this because the second parameter passed into `get_template_part` (i.e.  "excerpt" in this case) is tells WP to look for the "content" file with "-excerpt" appended to the name, and if it doesn't find that then use the standard "content.php".

Therefore what you actually need to do is create your own results display in a file called

**`/your-theme/template-parts/posts/content-excerpt.php`**

... and *not* content-search.php like the comments say!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/template-parts/**posts**/` - I left out the "posts" directory, but my file was in there. But I can experiment with a copy of `content-excerpt.php` instead of `content.php` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I think I'm on the wrong track, anyway.  The changes I made to `content.php` appeared inside its `entry-content` div, but that div does not appear in `content-excerpt`

Comment: @nev It was stuck at the end of my answer so you may have missed it, but you also need to pass "search" into `get_template_part` instead of "excerpt"

Comment: @nev I'm not sure what exactly the comments mean when they say to create a file called "content-search.php"... I'm wondering is that left over from older themes. What you actually need to do is create your own results display in a file called content-**excerpt**.php. I'll update my answer!